# Selection popping up when clicking the element on phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hello and thank you for passing by.

Here's what I mean: https://puu.sh/ymLzt/89944a9ec9.gif

And here´s the source code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rYzpEw

Here's the .css for the play button:

```
#pButton{
    height: 50px; 
    width: 50px;
    border: none;
  z-index: -1;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    outline:none;
    display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
      cursor: url(https://shopify.github.io/draggable/assets/img/cursor-rock.png),pointer;
  padding: none;
}
```

It only happens on phone screens.

Any ideas on what it can be? Thank you.

Comment: I am totally confused on what the issue is. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: Your gif appears to be on a desktop of the element working as expected. It sounds like on phones, instead of playing the animation, a selection box pops up instead. Is this accurate? If so, please give more details, if not, please explain what the actual issue is.

Comment: "Here's what I mean", "here´s the source code", "Here's the .css", "It only happens on phone screens", "ideas on what it can be".  What is "it"? You're being super vague here, man.

Answer (score -1):

> This is a correct answer, cursor: pointer; is really causing
>   highlight. But -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; is more
>   universal solution.

Fixed it with this.

The issue was the highlighting of the elements